# Removal of constant columns in R

Tags: r, constants

I was using the prcomp function when I received this error

```
Error in prcomp.default(x, ...) : 
cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance
```

I know I can scan my data manually but is there any function or command in R that can help me remove these constant variables?
I know this is a very simple task, but I have never been across any function that does this.

Thanks,

Comment: Please read the posting guidelines, and provide a small, reproducible sample `x`.  Right now we don't even know if your `x` is numeric, let alone a matrix. Now, if it is a matrix, `y <- x[,sd(x)!=0]` will suffice.

Comment: Probably not necessary if you are using prcomp on your data, but if you do have mixed column types, a simple solution is `x[,apply(x, 2, function(col) { length(unique(col)) > 1 })]`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem here is that your column variance is equal to zero. You can check which column of a data frame is constant this way, for example :

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=rep(1,5))
df
#   x y
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 1
# 3 3 1
# 4 4 1
# 5 5 1

# Supply names of columns that have 0 variance
names(df[, sapply(df, function(v) var(v, na.rm=TRUE)==0)])
# [1] "y"
```

So if you want to exclude these columns, you can use :

```
df[,sapply(df, function(v) var(v, na.rm=TRUE)!=0)]
```

**EDIT :** In fact it is simpler to use `apply` instead. Something like this :

```
df[,apply(df, 2, var, na.rm=TRUE) != 0]
```

Comment: Is this faster (or more robust) than my minisolution in the comment above? -- other than that I'm using an officially deprecated operation with `sd` :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Well, since the advice when you use `sd(x)` is to use `apply(x, 2, sd)`, I think it's quite the same, if you follow the advice :)

Comment: df[,sapply(df, function(v) var(v, na.rm=TRUE)!=0)] doesn't work for me: "undefined columns selected" error

Comment: Gives me the column contents but no column names!

Answer (score 15):

I guess this Q&A is a popular Google search result but the answer is a bit slow for a large matrix, plus I do not have enough reputation to comment on the first answer. Therefore I post a new answer to the question.

For each column of a large matrix, checking whether the maximum is equal to the minimum is sufficient.

```
df[,!apply(df, MARGIN = 2, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE) == min(x, na.rm = TRUE))]
```

This is the test. More than 90% of the time is reduced compared to the first answer. It is also faster than the answer from the second comment on the question.

```
ncol = 1000000
nrow = 10
df <- matrix(sample(1:(ncol*nrow),ncol*nrow,replace = FALSE), ncol = ncol)
df[,sample(1:ncol,70,replace = FALSE)] <- rep(1,times = nrow) # df is a large matrix

time1 <- system.time(df1 <- df[,apply(df, 2, var, na.rm=TRUE) != 0]) # the first method
time2 <- system.time(df2 <- df[,!apply(df, MARGIN = 2, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE) == min(x, na.rm = TRUE))]) # my method
time3 <- system.time(df3 <- df[,apply(df, 2, function(col) { length(unique(col)) > 1 })]) # Keith's method

time1
#   user  system elapsed 
# 22.267   0.194  22.626 
time2
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.073   0.077   2.155 
time3
#   user  system elapsed 
#  6.702   0.060   6.790
all.equal(df1, df2)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(df3, df2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I reran and found it's about 15% faster to use all(x==x[1], na.rm=TRUE) rather than computing max and min.

Comment: Position(function(x) !is.na(x), x) gives the index position of the first non-na element, and this spends much more time if x has some na values.

Answer (score 10):

Since this Q&A is a popular Google search result but the answer is a bit slow for a large matrix and @raymkchow version is slow with NAs i propose a new version using exponential search and `data.table` power.

This a function I implemented in [dataPreparation](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dataPreparation) package.

First build an example data.table, with more lines than columns (which is usually the case) and 10% of NAs

```
ncol = 1000
nrow = 100000
df <- matrix(sample(1:(ncol*nrow),ncol*nrow,replace = FALSE), ncol = ncol)
df <- apply (df, 2, function(x) {x[sample( c(1:nrow), floor(nrow/10))] <- NA; x} ) # Add 10% of NAs
df[,sample(1:ncol,70,replace = FALSE)] <- rep(1,times = nrow) # df is a large matrix
df <- as.data.table(df)
```

Then benchmark all approaches:

```
time1 <- system.time(df1 <- df[,apply(df, 2, var, na.rm=TRUE) != 0, with = F]) # the first method
time2 <- system.time(df2 <- df[,!apply(df, MARGIN = 2, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE) == min(x, na.rm = TRUE)), with = F]) # raymkchow
time3 <- system.time(df3 <- df[,apply(df, 2, function(col) { length(unique(col)) > 1 }), with = F]) # Keith's method
time4 <- system.time(df4 <- df[,-which_are_constant(df, verbose=FALSE)]) # My method
```

The results are the following:

```
time1 # Variance approch
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.55    1.45    4.07
time2 # Min = max approach
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.72      1.5    4.22
time3 # length(unique()) approach
#   user  system elapsed 
#    6.7    2.75    9.53
time4 # Exponential search approach
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.39    0.07    0.45
all.equal(df1, df2)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(df3, df2)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(df4, df2)
# [1] TRUE
```

`dataPreparation:which_are_constant` is 10 times faster than the other approaches.

Plus the more rows you have the more interesting it is to use.

Answer (score 3):

The `janitor` library has the comment `remove_constant` that can help delete constant columns.
Let's create a synthesis data for illustration:

```
library(janitor)
test_dat <- data.frame(A=1, B=1:10, C= LETTERS[1:10])
test_dat
```

This is the test_dat

```
> test_dat
   A  B C
1  1  1 A
2  1  2 B
3  1  3 C
4  1  4 D
5  1  5 E
6  1  6 F
7  1  7 G
8  1  8 H
9  1  9 I
10 1 10 J
```

then the comment remove_constant can help delete the constant column

```
remove_constant(test_dat)
remove_constant(test_dat, na.rm= TRUE)
```

Using the above two comments, we will get:

```
B C
1   1 A
2   2 B
3   3 C
4   4 D
5   5 E
6   6 F
7   7 G
8   8 H
9   9 I
10 10 J
```

NOTE: use the argument `na.rm = TRUE` to make sure that any column having one value and NA will also be deleted. For example,

```
test_dat_with_NA <- data.frame(A=c(1, NA), B=1:10, C= LETTERS[1:10])
test_dat_with_NA
```

the test_dat_with_NA we get:

```
  A  B C
1   1  1 A
2  NA  2 B
3   1  3 C
4  NA  4 D
5   1  5 E
6  NA  6 F
7   1  7 G
8  NA  8 H
9   1  9 I
10 NA 10 J
```

then the comment

```
remove_constant(test_dat_with_NA)
```

could not delete the column A

```
 A  B C
1   1  1 A
2  NA  2 B
3   1  3 C
4  NA  4 D
5   1  5 E
6  NA  6 F
7   1  7 G
8  NA  8 H
9   1  9 I
10 NA 10 J
```

while the comment

```
remove_constant(test_dat_with_NA, na.rm= TRUE)
```

could delete the column A with only value 1 and NA:

```
 B C
1   1 A
2   2 B
3   3 C
4   4 D
5   5 E
6   6 F
7   7 G
8   8 H
9   9 I
10 10 J
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are after a dplyr solution that returns the non-constant variables in a df, I'd recommend the following. Optionally, you can add `%>% colnames()` if the column names are desired:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = rep(1,5))
# returns dataframe
var_df <- df %>%
  select_if(function(v) var(v, na.rm=TRUE) != 0)  
var_df %>% colnames() # returns column names
```

Comment: `dplyr::select_if` is now superseded.

Answer (score 2):

tidyverse version of Keith's comment:

```
df %>% purrr::keep(~length(unique(.x)) != 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the function I use for data.frames

```
box::use(
  purrr[map_if],
)
#' Delete invariant columns
#'
#' @param df        data.frame  
#' @param exclude   string      do not remove these columns
#' 
#' @return
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
remove_invariant_columns <- function(
  df,
  exclude = NA
){
    
  cols <- map_if(
    .x = df,
    .p = is.numeric,
    .f = function(col) { 
      var(col, na.rm=TRUE) != 0 
    },      
    .else = function(col) { 
      length(unique(col)) > 1 
    }
  )
  
  cols <- names(cols[unlist(cols)])
  
  if(!is.na(exclude)){
    cols <- unique(c(exclude, cols))
  }
  
  return(df[, cols])

}
```