# How to normalize data consisting of few variables of zero value for all instances?

Tags: r, normalization

I want to normalize data instances(1000 instances and 400 features) such that each feature has zero mean and unit variance. However, some features have zero value for all instances and  hence svm() command from R e1071 package gives error signal as "In svm.default(x, y, scale = scale, ..., na.action = na.action) :  Variable(s) ‘X261’ and ‘X262’ and ‘X271’ and ‘X272’ and ‘X281’ and ‘X282’ and ‘X283’ constant. Cannot scale data. ".
How to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you should just remove the columns with zero variation (all values are the same) before scaling as they carry no information value what so ever. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068981/removal-of-constant-columns-in-r

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But won't it change feature distribution? These zero\constant(either of them) values correspond to one of the histogram bean bin values. Also there are such four different datasets and each has such zero/constant values for different bins. How to  compare their performance with these features if they are not the same for all? Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: sincerely I am no expert in machinelearning - what you could do with the svm.default() function is set scale = FALSE (https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Cannot-scale-data-td4663526.html) or you could separate the constant columns, scale the rest and merge the columns again for than to run some ml algorithm on it. Though still think, that a column with a unique value for all instances wont help your model to learn anything.... If you plan on mixing the four datasets the story might be diferent... also you have 400 features for 1000 instances - most probably you will have to do feature selection